# Does firebase automatically encrypt password? If I want to see the password that I entered on my Firebase app, how to do it?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
<Input placeholder="Password" type="password" value={password} 
        onChange={(e)=>{setPassword(e.target.value)}}/>
```

Would the above code work if I replace `password` by `text`, and is there any way input can be in terms of password (asterisks)?

Comment: I'm having problems understanding what you're asking here. Can you show the code that calls the Firebase API, and pinpoint what specific line of code doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen
I am making a form and there is a password field above, firebase automatically encrypts password, right ? 
so what I want is that user should see the field as password (the general password field where you type and it automatically takes in asterisk, doesn't show you actual letters that you type) but what I want is that I should be able to see the password they entered, in the backend.. This is not going to go in production, just trying to learn something new.

Comment: That all sounds doable and reasonable. What's the problem in your implementation of it? I.e. what line of code doesn't do what you expect it to do>?